# SVG 100% document height don't work

Tags: html, css, svg

I'm trying to fill a document with a SVG image using the width="100%" and height="100%" 
properties, I have height="100%" in html and body tags too, and different colours for body(red) and svg(blue).

Result is a full height svg but with a scrollbar in the right, and a thin line of red(body) at the bottom.

¿How can I fill the document with the svg without the scrollbar? Thanks.

The code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>SVG full page</title>
    <style>
      html, body {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        height: 100%;
        background-color: #ff0000;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <svg width="100%" height="100%">
      <rect x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" fill="#0000ff"></rect>
    </svg>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Add the `display: block;` CSS property to the SVG element.

You can see a demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/VL6z3/

Comment: it's working ! But WHY, WHY do we have to do this ? What make the svg tag behave this way ????

Comment: Setting SVG to display: block was the ONLY thing that worked in my case...  Otherwise I'd end up with extra pixels added to the body height below the SVG element (which creates havoc with printed media).  Nice (and simple) answer!  Thank you!